# Noscript forbid JAVA but accept JS?

Tags: security

Noscript forbid JAVA but accept JS? is this possible at all with noscript? if so how?

I want to use javascript to be able to se some content but i never want to turn Java on for any site i visit. I interpret the gui as noscript misses this option

Im using firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, Java is not a normal part of the browser. Just don't install any Java browser plugin, or remove it if it is there. It's not so cut-and-dried for every case, but http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/08/30/how-turn-off-java-browser/ (and many other sites, if you google for "disable java in browser") has more details. (The instructions are OS and browser specific, so it would be too much to replicate them here.)

Comment: The question is about noscript specifially, its for firefox. Its turned of for untrusted sites, but can it be turned of for all sites? Trusted and untrusted. I sometimes trust javascript but never java. I dont have a java plugin, does that mean that i dont have java in firefox at all?:O I have java jre installed